# Rails Many to Many Create Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, many-to-many, dropdownbox

and thanks in advance for any help offered here.  I'm new to rails development and stackoverflow actually.  I'm creating a many to many relationship and having trouble with some basics.  I'm wanting to do a User and Groups relationship.

Models:

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :name
      has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
    end

    class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :name
      has_and_belongs_to_many :users
    end
```

db/migrate create_groups_users_join

```
class CreateGroupsUsersJoin < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table 'groups_users', :id => false do |t|
      t.column 'group_id', :integer
      t.column 'user_id', :integer
     end
   end
 def self.down
   drop_table 'groups_users'
 end
end
```

I created a dropdown on my users form with this code.

> true }) %>

controllers

> ```
> def edit
>   @user = User.find(params[:id])
>   @groups = Group.all
>   ...
> end
>   def new
>   @user = User.new
>   @groups = Group.all
>   ...
> end
> ```

I'm lost now as far as what to add to the controller to update the join table on creations/edits/updates.  Can anyone explain what I need to change to make this happen?  Thank you.

Here's the Error output I am getting now:

```
 {"utf8"=>"✓",
    "authenticity_token"=>"pgyajCT23qQVMuS+MQgG6E7M7Q8AWjfGaYbe3q7QDSA=",
    "group"=>{"group_id"=>"1"},
    "user"=>{"name"=>"ymudfg"},
    "commit"=>"Create User"}
```

Comment: Your model looks good. Can you explain what exactly want to do??? I mean do you want to add user to particular group or group to user in your controller

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  What I am I trying to accomplish right now is when a user is created.  The created user and the chosen group are added to the groups_users table.  As of now my functionality is a created user but nothing added to the groups_users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add user to group by doing this in your controller:

```
   user = User.find(params[:uid])
   group = Group.find(params[:gid])

   group.users <<  user  #Adding user to group
```

For assigning group to user:

```
   user.groups << group
```

EDIT: As per your comment

```
  class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def new
      @user = User.new
      @group = Group.all
    end

    def create
      @user = User.new(params[:user])
      @group = Group.find(params[:group][:group_id]) # As per log
      if @user.save
        @group.users << @user
      else
        render :new
      end
    end

    #Similarly you can implement edit
  end
```

Comment: In the create action of the UsersController you probably want  User.new(params[:user]), not a find().

Comment: I really appreciate the help and I'm terribly sorry because you really are basically spelling it right out for me but I am getting an argument error with this "unknown key: group_id".

Comment: Can you post params from log. You have to use name of the drop-down(select tag) in place of group id.

Comment: Added log to original post.  Sorry for that mess above.

Comment: @clickit I have a new error now and have been embarrassed to admit it.  I've been searching to no avail. It's undefined method `users' for #<Group:0x00000002d45358> Thanks again for staying with me on this.

Comment: Never mind I did something exceptionally silly.  Thank you so much.

Comment: @fuller open your rails console and try this 'Group.last.users'. What it gives?

Comment: Group Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "groups".* FROM "groups" ORDER BY "groups"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "groups_users" ON "users"."id" = "groups_users"."user_id" WHERE "groups_users"."group_id" = 2
 => [#<User id: 10, name: "assembly", created_at: "2013-01-11 15:37:08", updated_at: "2013-01-11 15:37:08">, #<User id: 11, name: "assembly", created_at: "2013-01-11 15:38:44", updated_at: "2013-01-11 15:38:44">]

Comment: Is everything working fine now?? Same thing we are doing in controller adding user to group. Try creating new user from console and do Group.last.users << User.last

Comment: Yes everything is good now.  I feel I've learned quite a bit and really think I'm going to like ruby quite a bit after I get the hang of it.  Thanks again.  You've been outstanding!

Answer (score 0):

The association between users and groups is handled automatically by rails, this is why you added `has_and_belongs_to_many`.

If you want to add a user to a group, you could do:

`@group.users.create(params[:user])`

the other side you could do:

`@user.groups.create(params[:group])`

to find group of a user you could do:

`@user.groups.find(params[:id])`

Answer (score 0):

Now it's better to use: [has many through associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) than has_and_belongs_to_many